# AngularFireDatabase error on undefined data

Tags: firebase, ionic-framework, angularfire2

I have a problem. When I try to insert data into my firebase, it says ('subcribe' of undefined), I don't know why it's undefined, this is my code:

```
createProfile() {
    this.afAuth.authState.take(1).subscribe(auth => {
        this.afDatabase.object(`profile/${auth.uid}`).set(this.profile)
            .then(() => this.navCtrl.push('IndeksPage'));
    })
  }
```

I think, that "auth" is the problem, I am just following the tutorial, I don't know what this "auth" is. Can anyone explain it and solve my problem, thank you for your reply ..

Comment: You have `take(1)` written, did you mean to say `token(1)`? Considering your error, and because I have never seen the `take()` method I assume that is very likely your problem. However, could you  please write more about what you are trying to do? - because your code, currently, will do something different than just what you have described.

Comment: Have you imported `take` through the rxjs library? `import 'rxjs/add/operator/take';`?

Comment: i've done yet importing rxjs library in main.ts (app), but the program still have the same problem (undefined)